# Will channel keep my coroutine running if it doesn't receive any values by channel.send()?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I start to use `Channel` in `kotlinx.coroutines.channels` with android and I am puzzled about the lifetime of my coroutineScope when using channel.

```kotlin
val inputChannel = Channel<String>()

launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
   // #1
   println("start #1 coroutine")
   val value = inputChannel.receive()
   println(value)
}

launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
   inputChannel.send("foo")
}
```

It seems that if there is no value sent from `inputChannel`, `inputChannel.receive()` will never return a value and `println(value)` will not run, only "start #1 coroutine" will be printed.

My question is what happened to my `#1` coroutine when `inputChannel` receives nothing? Does it run into a `while(true)` loop and keep waiting? If it does, will it run forever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it will not run in "while(true)" loop.

Rather Coroutine#1 will get suspended at the line "inputChannel.receive()"

More details at
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/channels.html#buffered-channels

Regarding the "Lifetime" of CoroutineScope, it should be managed explicitly based on the Scenario.

For eg,  in below "MyNotificationListener Service", the CoroutineScope is tied to the LIFECYCLE of the SERVICE i.e. the Coroutines are launched in "onCreate()" and cancelled in "onDestroy()"

```
     class MyNotificationListener : NotificationListenerService() {

        private val listenerJob = SupervisorJob()
        private val listenerScope = CoroutineScope(listenerJob + Dispatchers.Default)
            
        override fun onCreate() {
            // Launch Coroutines 
            listenerScope.launch {
            }
        }

        override fun onDestroy() {
            // Cancel the Coroutines
            listenerJob.cancel()
        }
    }
```